# Power Supply Concept; Safety and Completeness - Feedback needed

Tags: power-supply, power-electronics, mains, feedback, circuit-design

I am currently designing a power supply for a circuit I have built.
I don’t have a great knowledge about PSUs, everything that I know I have learned in the internet. Unfortunately, my engineering degree starts only later this year but I want to finish this project before.
The power supply needs to be small which is why I chose a high frequency transformer.
My questions is: “Could the following concept be a working power supply and do I need to integrate anything other i.e. something like a control circuit for it to work or to increase safety?”

I want it to operate well and safely.

Summed (+ ~250mA buffer) current load is about 500mA. (Transformer rated for 700mA secondary current btw)

Current flow:

=> ***Wall Power Outlet (~230VAC out)***

=> ***Appropriate Fuse***

=> ***[(265VAC to 50VAC in) Step Down High Frequency SMD Transformer (~5VAC out)](https://www.mouser.de/ProductDetail/Wurth-Elektronik/750817014?qs=Bi9WzwbfiOhl3S5PIExHTw%3D%3D)***

=> ***(5VAC in) SMD Full Wave Bridge Rectifier (~5VDC out)***

=> ***(~5VDC in) Some array of capacitors to clean the signal [I don’t know the values and types yet] (~5VDC out)***

=> ***(~5VDC in) Stepping down the 5VDC for the chips accordingly through i.e. resistors***

Thank you in advance!

Comment: No, it will not work.  The transformer is meant to work in a flyback switchmode power supply, not directly from the mains.  You're much better off buying an off-the-shelf supply since safety is important and you don't have the experience necessary to be safe.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am not entirely sure about the current rating (would be enough on the dc side) but this (https://www.az-delivery.de/en/products/copy-of-220v-zu-5v-mini-netzteil?utm_content=link-to-full-site&utm_medium=amp&utm_source=shopsheriff) could work AND would be safe, wouldn’t it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the safety aspects, I will let the experts answer.

A few elements for you to consider :

- it is useless to have a high frequency transformer if you feed it directly from mains (ie at 50 or 60 Hz). If you want to go "high frequency", you need to do some PWM or similar (which usually means using an integrated circuit)
- I'm not even certain your transformer is well suited (saturation current at 375mA, made for switching frequency of 5kHz)
- when using full bridge rectification, remind that current has to go through 2 diodes (at 5V, that's a non negligible voltage drop). On the "good" side, your 5VAC is probably RMS, so between minimum and maximum, it is 2*sqrt(2) times more. You will probably not end up with 5V DC output.
- this transformer is NOT regulating the output voltage : so you will not get a stable 5V event adding an infinite amount of capacitors : at best, you will get a rather stable voltage somewhere around 5V, with some error proportional to the error on the mains voltage (up to 5-10% in most countries, even worse in some), and some changes based on the current you draw. So you have to be very careful about not exceeding the voltage limits for your circuit (some 5V components get destroyed at 5.5V)

So if your goal is just to finish your project, I would suggest you just buy a small module of the shelf and integrate it.

If your goal is to do it yourself, then take lots of precautions (mains are very dangerous if handled properly). The best solution is probably to follow some reference design.

In case you want more specific guidance, you will need to define clearly your requirements for the output (what load, min and max output voltages, maximal output ripple, ... otherwise even experts won't be able to say if your solution is correct)

EDIT : don't use resistors to step down voltage to supply circuits. If you need to be really compact, use linear voltage regulators (only 3 pins, and sometimes a pair of external capacitors). Using resistors is either extremely imprecise, or wasting a lot of energy (you waist at least 10 times the current you use). With liner regulators, you are precise, and use the same current as your load (you just waist the voltage difference). If you care about efficiency, then you need a switching regulator, but it is far more complex

Comment: Thank you for this thorough and rapid response! Good thing I decided to ask before building it. I would very much like to build it myself but that is probably not a great idea regarding my experience so I’ll post pone to another later project. Now, I am looking at something like this https://www.az-delivery.de/en/products/copy-of-220v-zu-5v-mini-netzteil?utm_content=link-to-full-site&utm_medium=amp&utm_source=shopsheriff . Do you think this could work?

Comment: At first glance (I haven't read the datasheet completely), I think it can work (note the capacitor recommended at the output). However, for components connected to the mains, I would recommend you buy them from trusted manufacturers/suppliers, providing decent datasheets. For this one, one critical element that is not specified is the isolation voltage (which makes me wonder if they do proper safety testings).

Comment: I bought parts from this German supplier in the past including a power supply and it still works but I didn’t find the isolation voltage spec either which is why I messaged them now. I’ll text back when they respond

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: Use a USB "charger" to get nice 5V at a couple of amps. You can buy them pretty much everywhere. The "charger" is a misnomer: those are USB *power supplies*. They don't do any charging at all (!).

A high frequency transformer needs to operate at... high frequency. Much higher than 1kHz for most such transformers. They typically work at ultrasonic frequencies, up to a MHz or two, depending on transformer design.

I'd advise you to use an off-the shelf switching supply - either brick-style, or a wall-wart, or a basic line-frequency rectifier + transformer design.

If your circuit can work from 5V, then USB "chargers" - really USB power supplies - are the simplest and cheapest.

If you want to be fancy and need higher voltage at higher current, use a USB-C PD powered device (PD) module that can "talk" to a USB-C power supply to have it provide higher voltage than 5V. But you seem not to need that.